# why fadeIn() function is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have done  a html Login page which needs to be animated once the page loads, i have added a java script function to do the same. But nothing happens. Here is my code,

```
 <div id="animate-wrapper" class="afterSlide">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form name="login" id="login" >
          <div class="row-fluid nowrap">
            <div class="input-container">
              <label>User Name:</label>
              <input id="d_username" name="d_username" autofocus="autofocus" type="text" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
              <label>Password:</label>
              <input id="d_password" name="d_password" type="password" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
              <label>&nbsp;</label>
              <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
              <input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en_US">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="eval-users-toggle-container">            
              <div id="eval-users-toggle">
                <div>Login as an Evaluator</div>
                <div id="eval-arrow" class="closed"></div>
              </div>

          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

And **Javascript**,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){          
      $("#login-background").fadeIn(1000, function() {
      $("#login-logo").addClass("afterSlide");
      $("#animate-wrapper").addClass("afterSlide");
      $("#d_username").focus();
      $("#login-footer").addClass("afterSlide");

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't close your `fadeIn()`s function parameter nor the method itself. So, syntax error.

Comment: Now i realised this was such a dumb quesiton! please no more dvs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Error console of your browser to tackle JavaScript problems.

First of all you are not closing the FadeIn() function parameter and the method itself.

**EDIT :**

Second problem here is your selector for the fadeIn(). When using an "#" as selector you are selecting by id, but you have no element with id "login-background". I;m guessing you want the whole div containing the form to fadeIn once the page is done loading. In that case you need to select the div by id "animate-wrapper".

Change you JavaScript into:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#animate-wrapper").fadeIn(1000, function() {
     $("#login-logo").addClass("afterSlide");
     $("#animate-wrapper").addClass("afterSlide");
     $("#d_username").focus();
     $("#login-footer").addClass("afterSlide");
 });
});</script>
```

Last problem here is that the fadeIn() method is trying to fade in a element which is already visible, therefore it is not doing anything. The element you are trying to fadeIn needs to have the style element "display:none" making it not visible at first.

You can change this by adding a style for your div with id "animate-wrapper" at the top of your CSS code, setting "display:none":

```
#animate-wrapper {
   display:none;
}
```

Or just adding it in the div itself (which is kind of the uglier solution):

```
<div id="animate-wrapper" class="afterSlide" style="display:none">
```

**EDIT 2 :**

If you want the form to slide in from left to the right, like you said in the comments you will have to modify your JavaScript a bit. jQuery does not have a method to slideIn horizontally. You will need to get the width of the wrapper, and animate show the element. Change the row of the fadeIn() method to this:

```
var wrapper_width = $("#animate-wrapper").width();
$("#animate-wrapper").width(0);
$("#animate-wrapper").show().animate({width: wrapper_width}, 1000, function() {
```

Comment: any idea still it does not work

Comment: I'm not really sure what it is supposed to do. There are a couple of things not adding up. For example: The jQuery selector for the fadeIn() method "#login-background" does not even exist. When using # you are selecting by id. You have no objects with id "login-background". Can you please elaborate what it is you want the script to do?

Comment: If I would quess you want the login form to fadeIn after the page is done loading and then focus on the username input? I will edit my answer

Comment: Just edited my answer. But I'm still not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the "afterSlide" classes since the whole div is not even visible before the fadeIn/"afterSlide"

Comment: @Sajeetharan You want it to slide in? You need a little work around for this. jQuery can fadeIn, slideDown and slideUp but not slide from left to right.

I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Close all the methods brackets properly and create all used ids.

Please check you import jquery (file/cdn) into you code. if no then add cdn into page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and you can use browser console (Shift+Ctrl+J) for check javascript error.

if you are newer then use firebug for debug javascript/jquery.